# Super expression must either be null or a function when try to install CheckboxTree library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkboxtree

I have this code :

```
import { CheckboxTree } from 'react-checkbox-tree';
```

The build successfully done. But in browser I get : `Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`

If I remove the import, the app is working fine.

Can you help me please ? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree/issues/210

Solution found in the above link. Solution is that either to use 'react-checkbox-tree-enhanced' package or upgrading the webpack. I tried 'react-checkbox-tree-enhanced' in my project. It worked.